# Rewriting a query into simpler form

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    PRD_QTY,
    CASE 
        WHEN PRD_QTY = 'TRUE' 
            THEN CONCAT(PRD_NO, ':', 'high') 
    END AS Test_1 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         ID, ORD_NBR, PRD_QTY,
         CASE 
             WHEN listagg(DISTINCT item_detail, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY item_detail) = '' 
                 THEN 'null' 
                 ELSE LISTAGG(DISTINCT split(item_detail, ';')[1]::text,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY split(item_detail, ';')[1]::text) 
         END AS PRD_NO
     FROM 
         (SELECT DISTINCT
              ID, A.ORD_NBR, C.PRD_QTY,
              REGEXP_REPLACE(item_detail,'\;;;;;.*$','') AS item_detail 
          FROM 
              Table_1 A 
          JOIN 
              Table_2 B ON A.ST_ID = B.ST_ID
          JOIN 
              Table_3 C ON C.ST_ID = B.ST_ID
          WHERE 
              DATE_COL = '2022-02-22')
     GROUP BY 
         ID, ORD_NBR, PRD_QTY)
```

Is it possible to rewrite this query into simpler form? I don't want to use multiple sub query.

Comment: It's interesting that you used my answer `split(item_detail, ';')[1]::text` but chose to accept the regexp answer.

Comment: Also of interest is that the CTE form that Lukasz offered is actually 100% the same as the nested SELECT form you had, so the SQL is only "improved" readability. Which is actually a merits reason to change forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be rewritten using common table expression(CTE):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT ID, A.ORD_NBR, C.PRD_QTY,
         REGEXP_REPLACE(item_detail,'\;;;;;.*$','') AS item_detail 
  FROM Table_1 A 
  JOIN Table_2 B 
    ON A.ST_ID = B.ST_ID
  JOIN Table_3 C 
    ON C.ST_ID = B.ST_ID
  WHERE DATE_COL = '2022-02-22'
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT ID, ORD_NBR, PRD_QTY,
       CASE 
       WHEN LISTAGG(DISTINCT item_detail, ',') 
            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY item_detail) = '' 
       THEN 'null' 
       ELSE LISTAGG(DISTINCT split(item_detail, ';')[1]::text,',') 
            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY split(item_detail, ';')[1]::text) 
       END AS PRD_NO
     FROM cte
     GROUP BY ID, ORD_NBR, PRD_QTY
)
SELECT ID, PRD_QTY,
  CASE WHEN PRD_QTY = 'TRUE' THEN CONCAT(PRD_NO, ':', 'high') END AS Test_1 
FROM cte2;
```

Answer (score 2):

A problem with this code is you are using DISTINCT in the `cte` (Lukasz context) select, and a DISTINCT is the same as a GROUP BY. So in `cte2` where it is `GROUP BY ID, ORD_NBR, PRD_QTY`, and stuff is done to item_detail, that is what the prior DISTINCT was doing..

Now for performance reasons it might be beneficial to do that in two steps, but that cannot be given as advice here on Stack overflow, as it is 100% your data related.

Then in `cte2` in the case you are turning a number of items into a list, and comparing it to an empty string. This is rather agitating. Because the only case logically is when you have a single null as `item_detail`, OR you have a single empty string (or the both at the same time) and anything else it will not be aggregate to empty string.

```
SELECT column1
    ,listagg(column2) as la
    ,la = '' as was_empty
FROM VALUES
    (1, ''),-- solo empty
    (2, null), -- solo null
    (3, null), -- both null and empty 
    (3, ''),
    (4, 'pot'), -- both pot and empty 
    (4, ''),
    (5, 'pot'), -- both pot and null 
    (5, null),
    (6, 'pot'), -- two valid strings
    (6, 'kettle')
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

| COLUMN1 | LA | WAS_EMPTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | TRUE |
| 2 |  | TRUE |
| 3 |  | TRUE |
| 4 | pot | FALSE |
| 5 | pot | FALSE |
| 6 | potkettle | FALSE |

the output of the first LISTAGG is just this test, thus if nothing else is learned the ORDER BY is 100% wasted. But what this code is trying to find is "are there any none empty string.

```
count_if(item_detail <> '') > 0
```

would be more readable and to the point than

```
LISTAGG(DISTINCT item_detail, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY item_detail) = ''
```

and anther that question you rip apart the `item_detail`'s anyways so that should be pushed higher up.

so `cte2 and cte` could be written as:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        ID, 
        A.ORD_NBR, 
        C.PRD_QTY,
        SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(item_detail, '\;;;;;.*$', ''), ';')[1]::text AS sub_value,
    FROM table_1 AS a 
    JOIN table_2 AS b 
        ON a.st_id = b.st_id
    JOIN table_3 AS c 
        on c.st_id = b.st_id
    WHERE date_col = '2022-02-22'
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT  
        id, 
        ord_nbr, 
        prd_qty,
        NULLIF(LISTAGG(DISTINCT sub_value, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sub_value), '') AS prd_no
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY 1,2,3
)
SELECT 
    id, 
    prd_qty,
    IFF( prd_qty = 'TRUE', CONCAT(prd_no, ':', 'high'), null) AS test_1 
FROM cte2;
```

because the `SPLIT()[1]::text` on null or too small data outputs as null:

```
SELECT column1
    ,SPLIT(column1, ';')[1]::text
FROM VALUES
    (null),
    (''),
    ('A'),
    ('A;B'),
    ('A;B;C');
```

gives:

| COLUMN1 | SPLIT(COLUMN1, ';')[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nI2a.png)::TEXT |
| --- | --- |
| null | null |
| "empty string" | null |
| A | null |
| A;B | B |
| A;B;C | B |

but if you want to mash `sub_value` in twice the SQL could be writen:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        id, 
        a.ord_nbr, 
        c.prd_qty,
        NULLIF(LISTAGG(DISTINCT SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(item_detail, '\;;;;;.*$', ''), ';')[1]::text, ',') 
            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(item_detail, '\;;;;;.*$', ''), ';')[1]::text), '') AS prd_no    
    FROM table_1 AS a 
    JOIN table_2 AS b 
        ON a.st_id = b.st_id
    JOIN table_3 AS c 
        on c.st_id = b.st_id
    WHERE date_col = '2022-02-22'
    GROUP BY 1,2,3
)
SELECT id, prd_qty,
  IFF( prd_qty = 'TRUE', CONCAT(prd_no, ':', 'high'), null) AS test_1 
FROM cte;
```

But if we go back to the LISTAGG example:

```
SELECT column1
    --,listagg(nullif(column2,''), ',') as la
    ,listagg(column2) as la
    ,la = '' as was_empty
    ,count_if(column2 <> '')
FROM VALUES
    (1, ''),-- solo empty
    (2, null), -- solo null
    (3, null), -- both null and empty 
    (3, ''),
    (4, 'pot'), -- both pot and empty 
    (4, ''),
    (5, 'pot'), -- both pot and null 
    (5, null),
    (6, 'pot'), -- two valid strings
    (6, 'kettle')
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

and we put a separator in:

```
listagg(column2, ',')
```

for the #4 value we get the answer `pot,`, so `sub_value` should really be `NULLIF(<value>, '')` at the time it was produced:

thus: the longer form would be:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        ID, 
        A.ORD_NBR, 
        C.PRD_QTY,
        NULLIF(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(item_detail, '\;;;;;.*$', ''), ';')[1]::text,'') AS sub_value,
    FROM table_1 AS a 
    JOIN table_2 AS b 
        ON a.st_id = b.st_id
    JOIN table_3 AS c 
        on c.st_id = b.st_id
    WHERE date_col = '2022-02-22'
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT  
        id, 
        ord_nbr, 
        prd_qty,
        NULLIF(LISTAGG(sub_value, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sub_value), '') AS prd_no
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY 1,2,3
)
SELECT 
    id, 
    prd_qty,
    IFF( prd_qty = 'TRUE', CONCAT(prd_no, ':', 'high'), null) AS test_1 
FROM cte2;
```

or the shorter form:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        id, 
        a.ord_nbr, 
        c.prd_qty,
        NULLIF(LISTAGG(DISTINCT NULLIF(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(item_detail, '\;;;;;.*$', ''), ';')[1]::text,'') 
                WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NULLIF(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(item_detail, '\;;;;;.*$', ''), ';')[1]::text,''), '') AS prd_no  
    FROM table_1 AS a 
    JOIN table_2 AS b 
        ON a.st_id = b.st_id
    JOIN table_3 AS c 
        on c.st_id = b.st_id
    WHERE date_col = '2022-02-22'
    GROUP BY 1,2,3
)
SELECT id, prd_qty,
  IFF( prd_qty = 'TRUE', CONCAT(prd_no, ':', 'high'), null) AS test_1 
FROM cte;
```

oh yes:

```
CONCAT(prd_no, ':', 'high')
```

is the same as

```
CONCAT(prd_no, ':high')
```

And given you can push that last IFF/CASE into the same code that the grouping is happening in:

```
SELECT column1
    ,listagg(distinct nullif(column2,''), ',') within group (order by nullif(column2,'')) as la
    ,nullif(la,'') as was_empty
    ,iff(column1%2=0, CONCAT(was_empty, ':', 'high'), null) as test_1
FROM VALUES
    (1, ''),-- solo empty
    (2, null), -- solo null
    (3, null), -- both null and empty 
    (3, ''),
    (4, 'pot'), -- both pot and empty 
    (4, ''),
    (5, 'pot'), -- both pot and null 
    (5, null),
    (6, 'pot'), -- two valid strings
    (6, 'kettle')
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

[image]

really the code could be:

```
SELECT
    id, 
    a.ord_nbr, 
    c.prd_qty,
    NULLIF(LISTAGG(DISTINCT NULLIF(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(item_detail, '\;;;;;.*$', ''), ';')[1]::text,'') 
            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NULLIF(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(item_detail, '\;;;;;.*$', ''), ';')[1]::text,''), '') AS prd_no,
    IFF( prd_qty = 'TRUE', CONCAT(prd_no, ':', 'high'), null) AS test_1 
FROM table_1 AS a 
JOIN table_2 AS b 
    ON a.st_id = b.st_id
JOIN table_3 AS c 
    on c.st_id = b.st_id
WHERE date_col = '2022-02-22'
GROUP BY 1,2,3;
```